# Distinct count with grouping condition (DAX)

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I am having problems with a DAX query and I hope you can help me :)

I want to create a measure that counts in how many sprints (identified as Iteration Path in the table) a User Story (identified as Title) has been present. However, if the user story has been closed (identified as State) in any sprint I want the measure to return a 0.

| Title | Iteration Path | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Subscription order intake | Sprint 10 | Active |
| Subscription order intake | Sprint 10 | Closed |
| Subscription order intake | Sprint 10 | New |
| Source of truth views for list prices and cost prices | Sprint 09 | New |
| Source of truth views for list prices and cost prices | Sprint 10 | Active |
| Source of truth views for list prices and cost prices | Sprint 10 | New |
| Source of truth views for list prices and cost prices | Sprint 11 | Active |
| Source of truth views for list prices and cost prices | Sprint 12 | Active |
| Source of truth views for list prices and cost prices | Sprint 12 | Closed |
| Sales order views | Sprint 06 | Active |
| Sales order views | Sprint 08 | Active |
| Sales order views | Sprint 09 | Active |
| Sales order views | Sprint 10 | Active |
| Sales order views | Sprint 11 | Active |
| Sales order views | Sprint 11 | Closed |
| Quotes with longer than 6 months delivery time. | Sprint 06 | New |
| Project economy - Data model | Sprint 06 | Active |
| PrimeServ assist - Data model | Sprint 06 | Active |
| PrimeServ assist - Data model | Sprint 08 | Active |
| PrimeServ assist - Data model | Sprint 09 | Active |
| Prepare Work shop and kick-off | Sprint 09 | New |
| Prepare Work shop and kick-off | Sprint 10 | Active |
| Prepare Work shop and kick-off | Sprint 10 | New |
| Prepare Work shop and kick-off | Sprint 11 | Active |
| Prepare Work shop and kick-off | Sprint 12 | Active |

Just as an example, the return value for "Subscription order intake", "Source of truth views for list prices and cost prices" and "Sales order views" will be 0. However, the return value for "Quotes with longer than 6 months delivery time" will be 1 and for "PrimeServ assist - Data model" will be 3. That will make something like the following table:

| Title | Measure output |
| --- | --- |
| Subscription order intake | 0 |
| Source of truth views for list prices and cost prices | 0 |
| Sales order views | 0 |
| Quotes with longer than 6 months delivery time. | 1 |
| Project economy - Data model | 1 |
| PrimeServ assist - Data model | 3 |
| Prepare Work shop and kick-off | 4 |

I hope I explained myself correctly, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table looks like this:

[image]

Measure:

```
   Measure = 
VAR t = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Table'[Title]), 
    FILTER('Table', 'Table'[State] = "Closed")
)
RETURN

CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Iteration Path]), 
    FILTER('Table', NOT ('Table'[Title] IN t))
)+0
```

Result:

[image]